# Unnable to get auth token after sign in with play services 7.5.+ (Android)

Tags: android, google-play-services

After updating my play services to the version 7.5.0, I have problems retrieving the authentication token to authenticate the app with my backend after doing the google+ sign in.

I'm following the documentation at [Google Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/). As said, the sign in works, I'm requested to select an account when the device has more than one, and to allow permissions for this app, and after that I try to get the token with an async task:

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
    Account account = new Account(accountName, GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    String scopes = "audience:server:client_id:" + SERVER_CLIENT_ID; // Not the app's client ID.
    String idToken = "";
    try {
        idToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), account, scopes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
    } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
    }
    return idToken;
}
```

I receive always a **GoogleAuthException Unknown**. I'm pretty sure that I'm using the right SERVER_CLIENT_ID, and that this SERVER_CLIENT_ID is well configured in the Google Developer Console (because this was working right with the previous version of the play services).

Anybody else is having this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem my self.

The new tool that generates a configuration file for the play services [Enabling google services for your app](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=com.google.samples.quickstart.signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Try%20Sign-In), offers a wizard that generate a json file that we have to include into our project.

The problem was that after choosing the app from the combo box, the wizard automatically suggested "com.mydomain" as android package name, but the right package name was "com.mydomain.app".

So the advice is take a second look to the package name in the google-services.json file.

I find this very difficult to debug!