# GoogleSignInAccount getServerAuthCode returns null on successful login

Tags: java, android, mongodb, mongodb-stitch

## Summary

I want to implement Google Service sign in for an Android app of mine, and for the most part, it's been working fine through the guidance of [this helpful tutorial](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java). I am exploring using [MongoDB Stitch](https://stitch.mongodb.com/) as my backend, I want to make Stitch the broker between my database and clients. Stitch provides this [not-so-helpful tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authentication/google).

## Problem

I am currently blocked by an issue where:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = 
        new GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient 
        = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    findViewById(R.id.signinwithgooglebutton)
        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Initiated Google onClick.");
                Intent signInIntent = 
                    googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = 
                GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);

            final GoogleCredential googleCredential = 
                new GoogleCredential(account.getServerAuthCode());
                                     // ^~~ returns empty String
            return;
        }
    }
```

## Expected behavior

`account.getServerAuthCode()` should return the server authentication code so I can pass it to Stitch and have it handle sessions for me.

## Attempts made

1. Refreshed oauth2-google client secrets.
2. Set up SHA-1 signing key for Android app.
3. Made sure I did not make typos like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611524).
4. Explicitly request server authentication code by calling `requestServerAuthCode` in Builder, like so:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = 
        new GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestServerAuthCode(getResources()
                .getString(R.string.server_client_id)) 
                     // ^~~ gets server_client_id from string.xml
             .build();
```

A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870165). Given that this question had no answer was not resolved, I don't think merging the two questions is advisable.

I am honestly stumped, all contributions are welcomed.

Comment: Can you add the `// ...` part of your code, so we can see what you're doing with `GoogleSignInOptions`?

Comment: @haley I just updated the post with the information you requested.

Comment: Do you also do this: `GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);`? I don't see where you get the account.

You can also try getting the account like this: `GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);`.

I've seen a lot of problems with this from other people who also are getting an empty string just googling around.
Just some thoughts!

Comment: I do use the `getResult(...)` call, but my issue lies with the `account.getServerAuthCode()` returns `null`, so I think the problem probably wasn't related to that. The `getResult(...)` call sometimes throws `ApiException DEVELOPER_ERROR`, sometimes it doesn't...

Hmm, good point, let me try and report back. A thought before I try though, I doubt the `getLastSignedInAccount(this)` method would work, because I've been developing my app using a fresh install and my device has never successfully logged in once, so I doubt I would be able to get anything back from that call.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using your serverClientId

```
String serverClientId = getString(R.string.server_client_id);
```

Comment: I don't see how changing a variable name could possibly fix this issue. Testing this also proves that it makes no difference. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use getServerAuthCode() change the object create method.

Use this

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestServerAuthCode(serverClientId)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();